# Linear Regression with np.arrays and scipy.stats

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, linear-regression, valueerror

I'm trying to do a linear regression on two 2x3 arrays, one of x values and one of y values where each row is a separate data set, but when I try to compute it on the whole array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress


sigma = [[10. 20. 40.]
 [15. 30. 50.]]
tau = [[ 7.  14.  28. ]
 [15.5 31.1 51.8]]

slope = linregress(sigma, tau)[0]
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

However, if I select the rows manually it works fine:

```
slope = linregress(sigma[0,:], tau[0,:])[0]
```

I know I could probably get what I want with a for loop, but I feel like there should be a more straightforward way that I'm just missing. Also, I know I could do this really simply without arrays, but I'd like to get this right so I can use it for much larger data sets in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Show your imports

Comment: apologies, done : )

Comment: The return value does not appear to be an array according to the docs

Comment: Okay, is there another way around my problem? I tried polyfit, but it gave me a similar result

Comment: Do you just want a slope?

Comment: You could just do your own least squares

Comment: Yes, all I want right now is the slope, but I'm really trying to understand how python/numpy is processing these arrays so that I can use them more effectively in the future. It seems like it shouldn't be that uncommon to want to perform some operation row-wise between two arrays with the output being a new array, but I'm coming up empty on ways to efficiently do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the straightforward solution is to actually have a `for` loop. You are using the linear regression module from SciPy and by reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) I think you cannot have the vectorized solution that you are looking for.

If you don't like the `for` loop solution, maybe because it would be too slow for the real datasets that you will have to cope with in the future, you can try a more compact solution using a list comprehension which are usually faster than simple for loops (but depends on the problem at hand and I don't have any detail about your real application).

So, you could try something like that:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

sigmas = [[10, 20, 40], [15, 30, 50]]
taus = [[7,  14,  28], [15.5, 31.1, 51.8]]

slopes = [linregress(sigma, tau)[0] for sigma, tau in zip(sigmas, taus)]
slopes
>>> [0.7, 1.037027027027027]
```

I think this is an elegant solution. It's a short one liner (less than 88 characters) and it's clear and it could also be potentially faster than an explicit `for` loop.

Or, as @MadPhysicist suggested, you could implement your own linear regression function using, for instance, NumPy, that can benefit from vectorization.

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't initially get why @MadPhysicist said to write my own linear regression, but now I get that doing so would bypass some of the trouble that numpy has in dealing with other modules. That list comprehension works great, I need to make more use of zip in the future